# Turning the next(), hasNext() iterator interface into begin(), end() interface

Tags: c++, iterator, c++14

I have to use an external library I cannot change. This library among others can tokenize specially formatted files by its internal logic. The tokenizer offers an iterator interface for accessing tokens, which looks like the following simplified example:

```
class Tokenizer {
public:
    /* ... */
    Token token() const; // returns the current token
    Token next() const; // returns the next token
    bool hasNext() const; // returns 'true' if there are more tokens
    /* ... */
};
```

I would like to implement an iterator wrapper for the presented `Tokenizer` which allows the use of standard [algorithms library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) (`std::copy_if`, `std::count`, etc.). To be more specific, suffice if the iterator wrapper meets the requirements of [input iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator).

My current trial looks like the following:

```
class TokenIterator {
public:
    using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
    using value_type = Token;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using pointer = const value_type*;
    using reference = const value_type&;

    explicit TokenIterator(Tokenizer& tokenizer) :
            tokenizer(tokenizer) {
    }
    TokenIterator& operator++() {
        tokenizer.next();
        return *this;
    }
    value_type operator*() {
        return tokenizer.token();
    }

private:
    Tokenizer& tokenizer;
};
```

I got stuck with implementation of functions like `begin` and `end`, equality comparator, etc. So, my questions are:

- How can I construct a `TokenIterator` instance which indicates the end of the token sequence (i.e. `hasNext() == false`) and how can I compare it to another `TokenIterator` instance to decide whether they are same?
- Is it a good approach if I return a value from the overload of `operator*()` instead of a reference?

Comment: What does `next()` return? Is that something you need to deal with?

Comment: @Barry, I edited my question to make it more understandable what does the `next()` and the other methods return. Because the `token()` returns the current token, the return value of `next()` isn't really important in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I recommend taking a close look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html

I find that it vastly reduces the amount of boilerplate needed for code like this.

Then, you have to decide how you wish to represent an iterator that has reached the "end". One approach is to make a default constructed iterator be the "end" iterator. It contains no object and you must not increment or dereference it.
The "begin" iterator is then a non-default-constructed iterator. It has an object and you can dereference it. Incrementing this iterator simply checks `hasNext()`. If true, set the contained object to `next()`. If false, clear the contained object and make this iterator look like like a default constructed one.

There shouln't be any problems returning by value from `operator*`. Even if you assign to a reference, lifetime extension will keep the value around until the reference goes out of scope. That said, any code that assumes such references remain valid over multiple iterations WILL break, so stick to simple `for (auto val : tokens)` or `for (auto& val : tokens)`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I successfully implemented my wrapper and it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

By the suggestions of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47403458/7893951) I successfully implemented the iterator wrapper I intended to do.

Here is an example implementation which corresponds to the example shown in the question:

```
class TokenIterator {
public:
    using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
    using value_type = Token;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using pointer = const value_type*;
    using reference = const value_type&;

    TokenIterator() : tokenizer(nullptr), token(value_type()) {
    }
    TokenIterator(Tokenizer& tokenizerToWrap) : TokenIterator() {
        if(tokenizerToWrap.hasNext()) {
            tokenizer = &tokenizerToWrap;
            token = tokenizerToWrap.token();
        }
    }
    TokenIterator(const TokenIterator& other) :
            tokenizer(other.tokenizer), token(other.token) {
    }
    reference operator*() const {
        assertTokenizer();
        return token;
    }
    pointer operator->() const {
        return &(operator*());
    }
    TokenIterator& operator++() {
        assertTokenizer();
        if(tokenizer->hasNext())
            token = tokenizer->next();
        else
            *this = TokenIterator();
        return *this;
    }
    TokenIterator operator++(int) {
        TokenIterator previousState = *this;
        operator++();
        return previousState;
    }
    friend bool operator==(const TokenIterator& lhs, const TokenIterator& rhs) {
        return lhs.tokenizer == rhs.tokenizer;
    }
    friend bool operator!=(const TokenIterator& lhs, const TokenIterator& rhs) {
        return !(lhs == rhs);
    }

private:
    void assertTokenizer() const {
        if(!tokenizer) throw std::out_of_range("iterator is out of range");
    }

    Tokenizer* tokenizer;
    value_type token;
};
```

For the compatibility with the [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), here are the necessary `begin()` and `end()` functions:

```
TokenIterator begin(Tokenizer& tokenizerToWrap) {
    return TokenIterator(tokenizerToWrap);
}
TokenIterator end(Tokenizer&) {
    return TokenIterator();
}
```

Comment: Your 'equals' can be simplified to `tokenizer == other.tokenizer`

Comment: @Caleth, you are right, I edited my example accordingly. Thanks for the remark!

Comment: Please never write code like `token = tokenizer->hasNext() ? tokenizer->next() : (tokenizer = nullptr, value_type());` Just use an if statement. Same goes for all your other usages of the comma operator.

Comment: @Barry, I'll take your advice. Removed the overused ternary and comma operators from my example.

Comment: Well done! But if what you want is code review, I recommend using codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Filipp, thanks for suggestion, maybe I'll post it there too. Actually I wrote this answer for the community as a working example, which is based on your answer.